# Getting Command "make:entity" is not defined. error in Lumen 5.8 with l5-repository package

Tags: php, lumen, lumen-5.8

I've installed Lumen 5.8 and l5-repository.
Here is my require list in composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish": "^5.8",
        "league/fractal": "^0.19.2",
        "prettus/l5-repository": "2.1.*",
        "prettus/laravel-validation": "^1.2",
        "robclancy/presenter": "^1.4"
    }
```

I've followed instructions provided in [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository)

**in bootstrap/app.php placed:**

$app->register(Prettus\Repository\Providers\LumenRepositoryServiceProvider::class);

But after publishing through the following command:

php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider"

No file has been generated in app/config directory

Then after running command

php artisan make:entity Post

Showing following error:

```
  Command "make:entity" is not defined.  

  Did you mean one of these?             
      make:migration                     
      make:repository                    
      make:seeder
```

To see command list I've tried "php artisan" command and found following result:

```
Laravel Framework Lumen (5.8.12) (Laravel Components 5.8.*)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Available commands:
  help                Displays help for a command
  list                Lists commands
  migrate             Run the database migrations
 auth
  auth:clear-resets   Flush expired password reset tokens
 cache
  cache:clear         Flush the application cache
  cache:forget        Remove an item from the cache
  cache:table         Create a migration for the cache database table
 db
  db:seed             Seed the database with records
 make
  make:migration      Create a new migration file
  make:repository     Create a new repository.
  make:seeder         Create a new seeder class
 migrate
  migrate:fresh       Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
  migrate:install     Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh     Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset       Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback    Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status      Show the status of each migration
 queue
  queue:failed        List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table  Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush         Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget        Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen        Listen to a given queue
  queue:restart       Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry         Retry a failed queue job
  queue:table         Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work          Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 schedule
  schedule:run        Run the scheduled commands
 vendor
  vendor:publish      Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
```

Is there anyone faced the problem and got solution?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message this morning. I am using Symfony 5.1.2 with EasyAdmin 3.
Performing `composer update`
updated some stuff, but the problem persisted.
I checked `.env.local` and it was set to `prod` instead of `dev`. Putting it back in `dev` made the trick for me.

Comment: Remember of upvoting the questions that are relevant for you! That will increase the chance someone will answer it!